# dataset groupByKey mapGroups only using 2 executors out 50 assigned

Tags: apache-spark, dataset

I have a job that loads some data from Hive and then it does some processing and ends writing data to Cassandra. At some point it was working fine but then all of the sudden one of the Spark operations has a bottleneck where only 2 cores are used even though the partition count it is set to 2000 across the pipeline. I am running Spark version: spark-core_2.11-2.0.0 
My Spark configuration is as follows:

```
  spark.executor.instances = "50"
  spark.executor.cores = "4"
  spark.executor.memory = "6g"
  spark.driver.memory = "8g"
  spark.memory.offHeap.enabled = "true"
  spark.memory.offHeap.size = "4g"
  spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead = "6096"
  hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = "nonstrict"
  spark.sql.shuffle.partitions = "3000"
  spark.unsafe.sorter.spill.reader.buffer.size  = "1m"
  spark.file.transferTo = "false"
  spark.shuffle.file.buffer = "1m"
  spark.shuffle.unsafe.file.ouput.buffer = "5m"
```

When I do a thread dump of the executor that is running I see:

```
com.*.MapToSalaryRow.buildSalaryRow(SalaryTransformer.java:110)
com.*.MapToSalaryRow.call(SalaryTransformer.java:126)
com.*.MapToSalaryRow.call(SalaryTransformer.java:88)
org.apache.spark.sql.KeyValueGroupedDataset$$anonfun$mapGroups$1.apply(KeyValueGroupedDataset.scala:220)
```

A simplified version of the code that is having the problem is:

```
 sourceDs.createOrReplaceTempView("salary_ds")
 sourceDs.repartition(2000);
 System.out.println("sourceDsdataset partition count = "+sourceDs.rdd().getNumPartitions());
 Dataset<Row> salaryDs = sourceDs.groupByKey(keyByUserIdFunction, Encoders.LONG()).mapGroups(
                new MapToSalaryRow( props), RowEncoder.apply(getSalarySchema())).
                filter((FilterFunction<Row>) (row -> row != null));
  salaryDs.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER());
  salaryDs.repartition(2000);
  System.out.println("salaryDs dataset partition count = "+salaryDs.rdd().getNumPartitions());
```

Both of the above print statements show the partition count being 2000

The relevant code of the function MapGroups is:

```
class MapToSalaryInsightRow implements MapGroupsFunction<Long, Row, Row> {
    private final Properties props;

        @Override
    public Row call(Long userId, Iterator<Row> iterator) throws Exception {
        return buildSalaryRow(userId, iterator, props);
    }
}
```

If anybody can point where the problem might be is highly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that there was a column of type array and for one of the rows this array was humongous therefore. Even though the partitions sizes were about the same  two of them had 40 times the size. In those cases the task that got those rows would take significantly longer.